# Creating a DB2 sequence with a specific START WITH value

Tags: db2, sequence

In Oracle we can do it like this:

```
declare current_max_value NUMBER;
begin select last_number+1 into current_max_value from USER_SEQUENCES where sequence_name = 'HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE';
execute immediate 'CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ__NEW_SEQUENCE MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH '||current_max_value|| ' CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE';
```

Is there a DB2 equivalent?

Comment: Please mark the answer. I have posted it long back

Answer (score 4):

DB2 has vaugely equivalent functionality.

If you just need to generate uninque keys then:-

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (
     GENERATED_KEY                    BIGINT
        GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1, CACHE 100),
     MY_DATA                          VARCHAR(1000) ...........
```

On the create table statement will accomplish this without too much fuss. Anytime a null value is encountered on an insert an new number will be generated.

If you need an actual sequence number to be used over several tables then:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ORG_SEQ
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 NO MAXVALUE
 NO CYCLE
 CACHE 24
```

will define a sequence you then use the "NEXTVAL" keyword anywhere you want the next number in you sql:

```
NEXTVAL FOR ORG_SEQ
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not fit my requirement. I need to create sequence with a specific start value, so that existing table can use the new sequence (i cant start the sequence at 1 because there are already existing data) and each table have to use a different sequence so that there will not be any "jumping" numbers.

Comment: You can RTFM here http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9//index.jsp .      Look at the "identity-options" syntax you find a "STARTS WITH " clause. Also for your requirements for a contiguous sequence you need to set the 'NO CAHCE' option but be aware that this will effectivly "single thread" any updates to the table.

Comment: if we could know how are dynamic sql statements executed in DB2 then we could address this problem

Comment: i some how managed to know the syntax and have posted the below answer which is the utilimate way to do that....

Answer (score 0):

After a great difficulty I was able to figure this out with DB2 syntax and here we go

`CREATE PROCEDURE SEQ_NAME

LANGUAGE SQL 

DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 

BEGIN ATOMIC

DECLARE MAX_VAL_NO INTEGER;

SELECT MAX(COL_NAME)+1 INTO MAX_VAL_NO FROM TABLE_NAME;

execute immediate 'CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_NAME  NO MAXVALUE NO CYCLE  START WITH '|| MAX_VAL_NO;

END

GO`

Could any one tell me why should we use `LANGUAGE SQL` and `DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1`

And what is the syntax used here, frankly speaking I really dont have an Idea but I hit it through trial and error method. Eagerly waiting to know what is the syntax is it either ANSI C or some other.

Appreciate if you could answer this. Also provide some links for good study.(**Not regular IBM links**)

Comment: You need "LANGUAGE SQL" as DB2 support procedures written in C,Java or PL/1. "DYNAMIC RESULT SETS n" is a hint to the optimizer telling DB2 you only expect n rows returned from the procedure. In older versions of DB2 an error would occur if less rows were returned.

Comment: oh gr8 James this is really helpful. :)